# Dependencies Symfony2

Tags: business-logic, symfony

I'm wondering if there is a proper way to check the dependencies.

For example I've got a `NewsBundle`. Now I'll have to check if there is a `CommentBundle`. If there is one, it should execute a few more Code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In addition to markymark's answer, you can check if a specific *service* exists from your controller (or any other container-aware code) with the following snippet:

```
if ($this->container->has('foo_service.alias'))
{
    // service is loaded and usable
}
```

If you're not sure of the exact alias of a given service, or just for kicks and giggles, you can run the console command `php app/console container:debug` to see all services registered with the container.

Comment: +1, your answer is clearer and correct to me as the above one. It's better to ask for services - and not for bundles.

Answer (score 2):

You could use class_exists on the main Bundle class that every bundle should have.

For example:

```
if (class_exists('Acme\CommentBundle\AcmeCommentBundle'))
{
    // Bundle exists and is loaded by AppKernel...
}
```

Comment: Dear @markymark, are you sure this will give you right result? Imagine situation:  bundle is present on the filesystem, but wasn't registered in `AppKernel` (meaning neither bundle's routes neither services were loaded). Isn't it true that `class_exists('Some\Name\Space\Class') will try to autoload the class even despite it wasn't registed with the bundle? I wonder what do you think about it? HTH

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271443/3027445 <- way better to check for service name instead of class name

Answer (score 0):

The [Kernel](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/index.html) class contains a list of helper methods to check if a certain class is part of an active bundle or if a bundle is registered.

```
public BundleInterface[] getBundles()
    Gets the registered bundle instances.

public bool isClassInActiveBundle(string $class)
    Checks if a given class name belongs to an active bundle.
```